# Restricting Solr Queries to Web Application

Tags: apache, security, authentication, solr

I have an instance of Solr (not Solrcloud) installed on my server, Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu), and would like to use with a php web application. I have password protected the admin page, but queries can still be run remotely. I want to restrict my Solr app so that it can only be queried (both read and write) by a web application (php, with Solarium) stored on the same server. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: This question is rather broad. Please show what research you've done so far. [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a server administration question, so it would be better suited on Superuser. That being said, you have a few options:

1. [Make Solr listen to connections](http://shal.in/post/127561227271/how-to-make-apache-solr-listen-on-a-specific-ip) on the internal or loopback interface only. This would be 127.0.0.1 or 192.168/16 etc. In solr.in.sh, you can send a parameter to Solr to tell it which IP it should bind to: `SOLR_OPTS="$SOLR_OPTS -Djetty.host=127.0.0.1"`
2. [Configure your firewall to only allow connections](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145929/how-to-ensure-ssh-port-is-only-open-to-a-specific-ip-address) from IPs that should be able to access Solr.
3. [Configure Solr Authentication and Authorization](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Authentication+and+Authorization+Plugins). Zookeeper is required to make this work (you'll have to be running in SolrCloud mode).
4. Unpack the bundled jetty and set up authentication there. This is not really a good idea, as it will make it harder to upgrade.

The methods suggested in 1 & 2 can also be combined with a proxying / forwarding web server that performs authentication in front of the service (using mod_proxy and friends on other httpds) if you need the service to be exposed through a non-trusted interface.

Comment: Thank you, I believe 1 and 2 and what I'm looking for.